# SAS ODS PDF Insert Link

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, sas, sas-ods

I am trying to do something that I think would be simple.  I want to insert a link to an xls workbook into a title on a chart generated in GPLOT and output through ODS as a PDF.

I have tried:

```
ods escapechar="^";
TITLE2 '^S={URL="\\it4\Project_Data\Daily_Detail.xlsx"} To go to the source data Click Here';
```

This simply displayed the text.

I then tried:

```
title2 link="\\it4\Project_Data\Daily_Detail.xlsx" "Click here to view table";
```

With this I get a link but it doesn't work.  It is recognized as a link in the PDF.  I can hover over it and see the address but the address is showing up as"file:///it4/Project_Data/\Daily_Detail.xlsx", When clicking on it nothing comes up.

What am I missing?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work" for the second one.  Doesn't work how?  what happens when you click on it?

Comment: What version of SAS?  The first method works fine for me (9.3).  That's the one I'd recommend.  The second method, it attempts to fix your link to a standard link format, which doesn't really work properly; you could fix it yourself (file:\\it4\Project_Data\Daily_Detail.xlsx) perhaps but the former is the 'better' solution.

Comment: I am using 9.4 but I just tried 9.3 and got the same result.  The text in the title2 statement just being printed out.  Could it be a setting, an environment issue or even adobe reader?  Everything that I have read tells me this should work.

Comment: See if you can run the example I posted in an answer (It's not really an answer but there's no good way to post that otherwise).

Comment: Your code works perfectly.  I can even put my filepath in your code and it gives me the link I want.  If I comment out all of my GPLOT statements an add your PROC PRINT it works fine in my code.  It appears to not want to work with the GPLOT statements.

Comment: Hmm.  I think GPLOT may be taking over the titles.  You might be able to get it to work with the IMAGEMAP option and then some combination of GPLOT options.

Comment: Appended to my answer a possible solution.

Comment: The NOGTITLE option didn't change anything.  The title is printing above the image, it is just printing out as text and not a link.  I will look at the IMAGEMAP option next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my machine:

```
ods pdf file="c:\temp\test.pdf";
   ods escapechar="^";
 title "^S={URL='c:\'}PROC PRINT";
 proc print data=sashelp.class;
 run;
 ods pdf close;
```

I get a PDF that has a blue box around the title, and if I click on the title I get asked if I want to open c:\ .

To use this in GPLOT, you may want to set NOGTITLE to get the title to not appear within the image:

```
ods pdf file="filename.pdf" nogtitle;
```

That should cause them to appear as text and then should work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I had:

```
ods escapechar="^";
TITLE 'Daily Report';
TITLE2 '^S={URL="\\it4\Project_Data\Daily_Detail.xlsx"} For source data Click Here';
options orientation=landscape;
axis1 order=(&mindate to &maxdate by week)
  offset=(3,3)
  label=none
  major=(height=1 width=1)
  minor=(number=6 height=.5 width=1)
  width=1;
PROC GPLOT DATA = Letters_Summary;
BY Category;
PLOT Number_Sent*date_sent=Category / haxis = axis1;
symbol interpol=join l=1 w=3;
WHERE category NE "Miscellaneous"
    AND category NE "Verification";
RUN;
```

This didn't work.  It appears that the label and label2 statements needed to be immediately before the GPLOT.  Now I have:

```
options orientation=landscape;
axis1 order=(&mindate to &maxdate by week)
  offset=(3,3)
  label=none
  major=(height=1 width=1)
  minor=(number=6 height=.5 width=1)
  width=1;
ods escapechar="^";
TITLE 'Daily Report';
TITLE2 '^S={URL="\\it4\Project_Data\Daily_Detail.xlsx"} For source data Click Here';
PROC GPLOT DATA = Letters_Summary;
BY Category;
PLOT Number_Sent*date_sent=Category / haxis = axis1;
symbol interpol=join l=1 w=3;
WHERE category NE "Miscellaneous"
    AND category NE "Verification";
RUN;
```

Now it works.  I am not sure why the options or axis statements would interfere with making the title a link.